# how do i break a button into smaller buttons in kivy (grid layout) without changing screen

Tags: python, kivy

for example, here is the code

.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class ScreenOne(Screen):
   pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
   pass

kv = Builder.load_file("testing.kv")

class ScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
   ScreenApp().run()
```

.kv vile

```
WindowManager:
    ScreenOne:

<ScreenOne>:
    GridLayout:
        size: root.height, root.width
        rows: 2
        Button:
            text: "Break this button into 3 smaller buttons"
        Label:
            text: ""
```

When the button is clicked, i wanted to break the button into 3 smaller buttons. Can you help me to make an on_release command to do it?

Comment: create 3 `Buttons` and add them to the parent widget when the button is clicked (`on_released`). then remove the initial `Button` from the parent widget.

Comment: can you show me the example of the code? I can't figure it myself. I need more knowledge since i still relatively new to coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ScreenOne>:
    GridLayout:
        btn: remove
        size: root.height, root.width
        rows: 2
        Button:
            id: remove
            text: "Break this button into 3 smaller buttons"
            on_press: root.break_into_three()
```

then in your `ScreenOne` class create a function named `break_into_three` and define it as follows:

```
class ScreenOne(Screen):
   
    def break_into_three(self):
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Button1'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Button2'))
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Button3'))
        self.remove_widget(self.btn)  # removes the initial Button
```

I don't have a working Kivy environment to test this but I think you get the point.

Comment: I got the point, but when I tried it, it displayed this following error:  AttributeError: 'ScreenOne' object has no attribute 'btn'

Comment: oh i get it, the btn in kivy must be written before the gridLayout. The code has worked now, thanks a lot for the knowledge sir